# Key event issue in winform c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

in my project i need to modified this pre-made code to change the layout of the game. So i want to add key events on my form for my navigation to 'WASD' instead of using a button to move the snake. But the problem here is that once i added the function to the form and test it to display on the console out, it gives nothing, not event error. I am no expert in this, so i hope someone kind enough to lead me to the right path, thanks.

This is the code and screenshot of my project.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        backgroundMusic.PlayLooping();


        this.AutoSize = true;
        boardPanel.AutoSize = true;

        //Set up the main board
        mainBoard = new Board(this);

        //Set up the game timer at the given speed
        clock = new Timer();
        clock.Interval = speed; //Set the clock to tick every 500ms
        clock.Tick += new EventHandler(refresh); //Call the refresh method at every tick to redraw the board and snake.

        duration = 0;
        score = 0;
        level = 1;
        modeLBL.Text = mode;

        gotoNextLevel(level);

    }

    private void keyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.W)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("W is pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

Design View of the form.
[image: Design view of the form]

Comment: You haven't actually registered the handler `this.KeyDown = new KeyEventHandler(keyDown);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that normally one of the `Control`s on your `Form` will have the focus and capture all key events.

To enable your `Form` raise a `KeyDown` event when a key is pressed while a child control has the focus, set the [`KeyPreview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview) property of your `Form` to true:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    backgroundMusic.PlayLooping();

    this.AutoSize = true;
    this.KeyPreview = true; // <-- add this line
```

Comment: i believe this should be the correct answer. 99.9% of the issues with key presses on winform come down to form.KeyPreview

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, at first i tried to search for the 'keyPreview' but nowhere to be found, now i know that i need to type it in the code itself instead of looking from the form's property menu. haha..

Comment: @Jatiz but it actually is in the form's property window :) "KeyPreview" between "IsMdiContainer" and "Language" (if sorted alphabetically).

Comment: @RenéVogt huh...unfortunately i still couldn't find it in the property window. but i guess its ok, i rather do the code than clicking all the way in property window without knowing what it means..